# Native library in tomcat

Tags: tomcat, gdal

I have a problem with a native library: `ogrjni.dll`.

I put `ogrjni.dll` in `tomcat/shared/lib` and added this directory to the PATH variable. But get the errors:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.geotools.data.ogr.OGRDataStore
test.Read.getKadnum(Read.java:56)
```

And

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.gdal.ogr.ogrJNI.GetDriverCount()I
org.gdal.ogr.ogrJNI.GetDriverCount(Native Method)
org.gdal.ogr.ogr.GetDriverCount(ogr.java:98)
org.geotools.data.ogr.OGRDataStore.<clinit>(OGRDataStore.java:169)
test.Read.getKadnum(Read.java:56)
```

How can I get this to work?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `java.library.path` to include the place where you put your `.dll` file.

Note that your `.dll` will also have to have the same architecture as your JVM... that is, they must be both 32-bit or 64-bit, not one of each.

Answer (score 0):

I have the similar problems today when I call cplex with tomcat.
Just add the code below in ur servlet.

```
System.load(".../tomcat/shared/lib/ogrjni.dll");
```

In my servlet is:

```
System.load("D:/Program Files/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio125/cplex/bin/x64_win64/cplex125.dll");
```